# AWS CodeCommit does not work with HTTPS on OSX

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

After following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-unixes.html, I get the following error when trying to clone:

```
git: 'credential-aws' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

This is what is is in my .gitconfig:

```
[credential]
        helper = aws configure codecommit credential-helper $@
        UseHttpPath = true
```

I'm on OSX El Capitan.

Comment: Change the helper to helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@ and see if you are getting that error?

Comment: That was the issue. Any idea why it generated the .gitconfig incorrectly?

Comment: Don't know must have been error in a command you ran while setting this up. Please mark my answer as correct  if that solved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your gitconfig. Change it to below and it will work.

```
[credential]
        helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@
        UseHttpPath = true
```